# After submitting the form,I received null value in the controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

When I submit the form, I get null Value in the controller.(asp.net core 3.x)
How can I solve this problem?

```html
@model Alpha.ViewModels.ArticleViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "View";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

<div class="col-12">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Article", new {area = "Admin"}, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            
            @*<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>*@

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Article.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Article.Title" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Article.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            
             <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save changes" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(ArticleViewModel articleViewModel)
    {// articleViewModel.Article is null  why??????
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }
        return View(articleViewModel);
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace Alpha.ViewModels
{
public class ArticleViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public Article Article { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just only related tags
    /// </summary>
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Related tags in the set of all tags
    /// </summary>
    public List<Tag> AllTags { get; set; }
}
}
```

[image: Break point in very first of Edit action]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core` package to my project and then everything was okay!

> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core -Version 2.2.5

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/